# Delete words in a string within variable

Tags: php

I could use some help. How can I delete words in a string within variable? For Example:

```
$var = "test1 test2 ui"; $string="fru test1 frhu test2 vrui ui fehugr";
```

The output should be:

```
fru fru vrui fehugr
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) function:

```
$ret = str_replace(explode(' ', $var), '', $string);
```

Answer (score 2):

@xdazz, unfortunately, your code does not return the requested output.

Since Filippo only wants to replace /real/ words, that starts with nothing/whitespace and ends with whitespace/new-line/nothing, you need a regular expression for it.

```
$exp = '/(^|\s)('.str_replace(' ', '|', preg_quote($var, '/')).')(?=(\s|$))/';
$string = trim(preg_replace($exp, '', $string));
```

This replaces only real words.

Comment: Thanks you mate, but the code xdazz was fine. I still put a +1 to thank you :)